# STM32F105 USB Virtual Port Com

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-drive, stm32cubeide, stm32f1

I'm having trouble making stm32 work as a communication port over USB.

I can't believe it's so difficult to send a string over USB.

I created a new project using STM32CubeIDE.

I performed the following steps:

1. RCC -> HSE Crystal Enabled (25MHz)
2. USB_OTG_FS -> Device_Only
3. USB_DEVICE -> Communication Device Class (Virtual Port Com)
4. Clock Configuration -> Automatic Resolve. USB 48MHz.
5. Heap Size -> 0x800, Stack Size 0x800.
6. GPIO -> Pin 30. Output Led
7. Added 5s delay before while loop.
8. Added led blink code in the while loop.
9. Added CDC_Transmit_FS in the while loop.

When executing the program, the led flashes at the correct time (500ms) and the CDC_Transmit_FS function returns USBD_BUSY.

And Windows 10 does not detect the USB device.

I tested it on two different computers.
I tested inverting the D+ and D- signals of the USB cable.
I installed "STM32 Virtual COM Port Driver".

I'm using a custom PCB, and this PCB has an older code that was not generated by the STM32CubeIDE where the USB port reads pendrives.

So I believe the hardware is correct.

**
STM32F105RBT6
ST-Link V2
Windows 10
**

Any ideas?

````
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    uint8_t buffer[] = "Hello World\r\n";
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_Delay(5000);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_ON_GPIO_Port, LED_ON_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(500);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_ON_GPIO_Port, LED_ON_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_Delay(500);
    CDC_Transmit_FS(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}```
````